# Whats permissions are required to view the GCP datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

When viewieng the datastore page:

```
There was an error while loading /datastore/welcome?project=***********&folder=&organizationId=

Minimum permissions required for this page:
    appengine.applications.create
    datastore.locations.list
    servicemanagement.services.bind
    All permissions checked for the current project:
    appengine.applications.create
    datastore.locations.list
    servicemanagement.services.bind
```

I have 'Editor' as well as 'Cloud Datastore Owner' permissions.

What else do I need?

Comment: This two roles should be enough, I can view everything with this two roles. Are you sure using correct account?

Comment: Yes I am using the correct account.

Comment: That url is a bit unusual, how did you get to it? When I try to go to the equivalent one for my project I'm redirected to a url without the `organisationId` parameter. Was the organisation config ever attempted for your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those roles should be enough to view the project's Cloud Datastore instance. However, a few things in your post indicate that you're trying to create a Datastore instance, and to do that, you'll also need the `appengine.applications.create` permission if your project doesn't have an App Engine app.

[Cloud Datastore depends on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#enable-datastore). You don't have to use App Engine at all but you do need an active app to use Datastore.

You can have a project owner create the Datastore instance for you first, or you can ask them to give you the `appengine.applications.create` permission using a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles).

Comment: I'm not able to verify this, but I'm fairly sure you're correct. It does seem odd though that `Editor` role would not have this permission though?

Comment: It does seem odd, but yes, the project `Owner` role is the [only pre-defined role that let's you create a new App Engine app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control#primitive_roles).